# PowerShell - List all folder and subfolders in TreeView GUI Element

Tags: powershell, user-interface, treeview

I'm trying to list all the directories and subdirectories of the drive C: in a TreeView PowerShell element.

For now it only lists one instance of subfolders but I can't select those to see the directories in them.

Here is the code:

```
function tree {

   [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
   [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

   $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
   $Form.Text = "Files"
   $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(390, 390)

   $TreeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
   $TreeView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(48, 12)
   $TreeView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(290, 322)
   $Form.Controls.Add($TreeView)


   $rootnode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
   $rootnode.text = "Root"
   $rootnode.name = "Root"
   [void]$TreeView.Nodes.Add($rootnode)


   $array=@(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users)
   Write-Host $array
   foreach ( $obj in $array ) {                                                                                                             
        Write-Host $obj
        $subnode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
        $subnode.text = $obj
        [void]$rootnode.Nodes.Add($subnode)
     }

   $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
   [void] $Form.ShowDialog()

   }
   tree
```

This is the GUI in action:
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ir1d.jpg)

Thanks for everybody who contributes to this question.

Comment: You're going to need to call a method recursively to include all the subfolders and their subfolders, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a function inside your main function that recursively adds nodes to the treeview.

In the code below, I have changed the name of your function `tree` into `Show-DirectoryTree` to have it conform to the `Verb-Noun` naming convention of PowerShell functions.

Also, instead if hard-coding the root folder path, I added a parameter `RootFolder` to the function to make it more flexible in use.

```
function Show-DirectoryTree {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$RootFolder
    )

    # recursive helper function to add folder nodes to the treeview
    function Add-Node {
        param (
            [System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode]$parentNode, 
            [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Folder
        )
        Write-Verbose "Adding node $($Folder.Name)"
        $subnode      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
        $subnode.Text = $Folder.Name
        [void]$parentNode.Nodes.Add($subnode)
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.FullName -Directory | ForEach-Object {
            Add-Node $subnode $_
        }
    }

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Text = "Folders"
    $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(390, 390)

    $TreeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
    $TreeView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(48, 12)
    $TreeView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(290, 322)
    $Form.Controls.Add($TreeView)

    $rootnode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
    # get the name of the rootfolder to use for the root node
    $rootnode.Text = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($RootFolder.TrimEnd('\'))  #'# or use: (Get-Item -Path $RootFolder).Name
    $rootnode.Name = "Root"
    [void]$TreeView.Nodes.Add($rootnode)
    # expand just the root node
    $rootNode.Expand()

    # get all subdirectories inside the root folder and 
    # call the recursive function on each of them
    Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        Add-Node $rootnode $_
   }

   $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
   [void] $Form.ShowDialog()

   # remove the form when done with it
   $Form.Dispose()
}

# call the function to show the directory tree 
# take off the -Verbose switch if you do not want console output
Show-DirectoryTree -RootFolder 'C:\Users' -Verbose
```

Comment: Thanks for the great code snippet. Short, precise and works. I used it to enumerate a subtree in Active Directory